# Why does R show a package error immediately when I open the program?

Tags: r, windows, file-permissions, bioconductor

When I open R, before I type in any commands, the console immediately shows an error indicating that the `curatedMetagenomicData` package is not installed.

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error in library("curatedMetagenomicData") : 
  there is no package called ‘curatedMetagenomicData’
```

`curatedMetagenomicData` is a Bioconductor package I used a few years ago and which I must have removed at some point. When I try to reinstall it, the installation fails, seemingly because it isn't installed already?

```
> BiocManager::install("curatedMetagenomicData")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Installing package(s) 'curatedMetagenomicData'
installing the source package ‘curatedMetagenomicData’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/experiment/src/contrib/curatedMetagenomicData_3.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1855762 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

Error in library("curatedMetagenomicData") : 
  there is no package called 'curatedMetagenomicData'
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\jpennycook\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqcBkUu\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘curatedMetagenomicData’ had non-zero exit status
```

This seems to cause problems in unexpected places, such as when I try to knit an R Markdown document (completely unrelated to `curatedMetagenomicData`), which fails with the following message in the 'Render' window of RStudio.

```
Error in library("curatedMetagenomicData") : 
  there is no package called 'curatedMetagenomicData'
Execution halted
```

I've tried removing my R and RStudio installations as thoroughly as I can, then re-installing, but the issue persists. I can't understand what is prompting R to check if this package is installed. Can anyone help me understand this? I don't currently need to use the package in question, but the errors are becoming a pain.

EDIT:

This issue is also cropping up when I try to install any package from source (whether it's `curatedMetagenomicData` or another, such as `dbplyr`). In each case, the problem is apparently that curatedMetagenomicData is not already installed.

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/jpennycook/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqcBkUu/downloaded_packages/curatedMetagenomicData_3.4.2.tar.gz",
+                  repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jpennycook/Documents/myRlibs’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in library("curatedMetagenomicData") : 
  there is no package called 'curatedMetagenomicData'
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/jpennycook/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqcBkUu/downloaded_packages/curatedMetagenomicData_3.4.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

> install.packages("C:/Users/jpennycook/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqcBkUu/downloaded_packages/dbplyr_2.2.0.tar.gz",
+                  repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jpennycook/Documents/myRlibs’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in library("curatedMetagenomicData") : 
  there is no package called 'curatedMetagenomicData'
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/jpennycook/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqcBkUu/downloaded_packages/dbplyr_2.2.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Appears you have a problem that is very common among Windows users. There is a package dependency MASS and it failing to be updated in C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library because of a permissions issue. Solve that problem and the process may move to completion. You can probably find many asked and answered questions about enabling write access to the R package library on the web or in SO.

Comment: When I went searching, I found an unanswered question that had a comment pointing me to the R-windows FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-don_0027t-have-permission-to-write-to-the-R_002d4_002e2_002e0_005clibrary-directory

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks very much for this advice. I was able to set up an R package library in a writable location and install MASS in this new library, but it doesn't seem to have solved my problem. I've updated my answer with the new output when I try to install 'curatedMetagenomicData', which seems to be largely the same except for not mentioning MASS.

Comment: I do not see a link to either a Windows or Mac binary at that packages webpage: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/curatedMetagenomicData.html . Are you properly set up to compile source packages, i.e. do you have Rtools set up properly for R 4.2.0?

Comment: @IRTFM Another useful thought, and no I wasn't. I have now installed Rtools (I think successfully, since find_rtools() returns TRUE), but curatedMetagenomicData still won't install and the issue otherwise persists (see edit). I'm mostly confused why the lack of curatedMetagenomicData on my computer is causing R to show an error every time I boot it up, and preventing me from knitting an Rmarkdown document or installing dbplyr, which seem like entirely separate tasks that shouldn't require the package.

Comment: other possibilities: do you have a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory that is trying to load packages, **or** do you have a `.RData` file in your current working directory that has an object in it that will trigger the loading of this package?

Comment: And to expand on Ben's questions: do you understand that .Rdata files are invisible on File Manager unless you configure it to show files whose names begin with a period?

Comment: @BenBolker Ah brilliant, I found a `.Rprofile` file containing a script I wrote years ago that called for `curatedMetagenomicData`; no idea how it ended up as an `.Rprofile` file. I deleted it and this seemed to solve my problems. @IRTFM I didn't know that, I'm sure that will save me another question down the line! Thanks both very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on responses in the comments, I'll promote my comment to an answer.

Two possible causes of this problem are

- you have a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory that is trying to load packages
- you have a `.RData` file in your current working directory that is being auto-loaded; it has an object in it that will trigger the loading of this package

Note that in either case files whose names start with a `.` are usually invisible by default in file managers/file listings, so you may have to search for them carefully

`file.exists(".RData")` and `file.exists("~/.Rprofile")` will tell you whether these files exist; you could diagnose the problem by moving/renaming each one temporarily.